# A trigonometric proof

Tags: trigonometry

How to prove the following?
$${1-\sin A \over1+\sin A} = (\sec A- \tan A)^2$$

this is what I've done till now:
\begin{array}{ccc}
{1-\sin A \over1+\sin A} &=& {1+\sin^2 A - 2\sin A \over 1-\sin^2A} \\ \\
&=&1+1-\cos^2A-2\sin A \over \cos^2A \end{array}

How shall I proceed?

***EDIT***: I've got my answer, but I now have another question. Can this be proved by working on the Right hand side of the equation? In this case, how would you infer the LHS from RHS?

Comment: you are already done just use that $1-cos^2A=sinA$. do you see the solution now?

Comment: @Albanian_EAGLE You're missing a square in $\sin ^2 A$. OP is close, but not immediately there yet.

Comment: true, I am sorry. how can I edit my comment?

Comment: @Albanian_EAGLE Now, you can't. The editing possibility expires after 3 min, I think.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\frac {1-\sin A}{1+\sin A} = \frac {\left( 1-\sin A\right)^2}{\cos^2 A} = \left( \frac 1{\cos A} - \frac {\sin A}{\cos A}\right)^2 = \left(\sec A-\tan A\right)^2
$$

Comment: I think you mean "$\equiv$" in place of "$=$". Writing $f(x)=g(x)$ asks the question: for which values of $x$ do $f$ and $g$ agree? Writing $f(x) \equiv g(x)$ makes the statement that $f$ and $g$ agree for all values of $x$.

Comment: @FlybyNight No one asked question so far.

Answer (score 2):

As a matter of strategy, I would advise working with the right-hand side instead. The reason is non-mathematical: we are much more familiar with $\sin$ and $\cos$ than with $\sec$, and perhaps even $\tan$.

Rewrite $\sec A$ and $\tan A$ in terms of sine and cosine. We get
$$\left(\frac{1}{\cos A}-\frac{\sin A}{\cos A}\right)^2=\frac{(1-\sin A)^2}{\cos^2 A}.$$
Now, if we take a little peek at the left hand side, it is natural to replace $\cos^2 A$ by $1-\sin^2 A$, and note that this factors as $(1-\sin A)(1+\cos A)$.

Comment: I think you mean "$\equiv$" in place of "$=$". Writing $f(x)=g(x)$ asks the question: for which values of $x$ do $f$ and $g$ agree? Writing $f(x) \equiv g(x)$ makes the statement that $f$ and $g$ agree for all values of $x$.

Comment: @FlybyNight: That would be a matter of "local" convention. The symbol $=$ is also used to mean identically equal, I would guess more frequently than $\equiv$. In principle, it might be nice if notation avoided all ambiguities. In practice, it seems to be useful to "overload" certain symbols.

Comment: The addendum "for all $x$" should be used when "=" is being used to denote an identity. Otherwise, how do we distinguish between "$x=1$" and "$\cos^2x + \sin^2x = 1$"?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_%28mathematics%29#Identity_relation

Comment: @FlybyNight From context where this expressions are written.

Comment: I do agree with your advice.

Comment: @IasafroMaesman One of the main pillars of mathematical rigour is precision. Leaving things to be deciphered from context is not an act of precision. Use "=" and write "for all $x$", or use "$\equiv$". If you spend time thinking about my point, you will agree that it is correct. I understand that people might disagree because they don't follow the notational convention that I am emphasising. But formally, there is a difference; a difference many people choose to ignore or don't realise. I myself, used to use "=" all the time.

Comment: @FlybyNight In Portugal during my school days in the 1960's the distinction of "$\equiv$" and "$=$" was made in (Elementary) Algebra, but at the same time in the Trigonometry text book all identities were written with "$=$".

Comment: @AméricoTavares: An interesting feature of school trigonometric identities is that they are purely formal. For example, in the identity of the OP, the left side is defined at $\pi/2$, and the right side is not, but one is not expected even to comment.

Comment: @FlybyNight In general your convention is followed by all of us, but when answering about a trigonometric identity, we deduce from context that obviously we are speaking about "all $x$" although we don't say it explicitly.
We have to distinguish between rigor when writing a complete statement, an article or other thing and rigor when answering a question. Depending on the context we can be more rigorous or not.